# cljs.reader/read-string and regular expression

Tags: clojurescript

Is this a bug or by design? It seems like CLJS reader cannot read regular expressions:

```
(cljs.reader/read-string (pr-str #"a"))
```

> ## error {:message "EOF while reading.", :data {:type :reader-exception, :ex-kind :eof}}

Clojurescript v1.9.908

UPDATE: It works with v1.9.229 and Clojure 1.8.0. I'll try to see which version broke that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cljs.reader/read-string` only reads data in edn format & clojure regular expression `#"..."` syntax is not part of edn specification. (see http://edn-format.org)

https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.reader/read-string

> Reads one object from the string s. Returns nil when s is nil or
>   empty.
>
> Reads data in the edn format (subset of Clojure data):
>   http://edn-format.org
>
> opts is a map as per cljs.tools.reader.edn/read

Comment: Is it impossible to make the reader understand regex or could a correct opts map do the trick?